# Windows computer only able to use none Windows operating systems

Tags: windows, ubuntu, operating-systems, virus

I have a Windows computer that one day just blue screened when i tried turning it on... Whenever i turned it on, it just got to the Windows logo, did the progress bar for a few seconds, then restarted... it kept in this infinite loop just shutting itself down, and turning itself back on, until i pressed the power button. so one day i get a disc with ubuntu on it, and give it a try. it comes straight on. thank the lord! all my old files and family photos and things... so that's all good, but the computer won't install anything to do with windows. it won't install windows xp, windows 7, windows 10... the only other i've tried is ubuntu, and that works perfectly. does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Since ubuntu is working, Try creating bootable disk using [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/create-bootable-windows-10-usb-ubuntu) guide. Then using this you can repair or reinstall windows.

Comment: “Progress bar?” How old is this computer and what OS were you running? You should perform a surface scan on the hard drive first and see if it is any good. Sounds like this is an old computer. https://www.lifewire.com/free-hard-drive-testing-programs-2626183

Comment: it is indeed an old computer. it was running Windows XP. thanks for your help. i'll try give that a go whenever i can.

Comment: Just keep Ubuntu, since it works, and XP is a dead end. Using it is not much different from using Windows, Ubuntu can run many Windows apps, and it comes with a browser (Firefox), email (Thunderbird) and office (Liberoffice).

Comment: Deal with it, is not my type of answer DrMoishe

Comment: Turn the PC on and start hitting the F8 key about 1/sec.  You will get a text menu, select "disable automatic restart....".  Let it crash to a bluescreen, and use another device like a phone to do a screen capture.  Post the results here.  Most of it is boiler plate text but its the STOP code and a couple line above or below that that is really important.  Probably bad sectors, need to boot a Windows installer and get to the command prompt.  chkdsk /r c:  After that finishes repeat on any other drive letters.  Reboot with no bootable CD/DVD/ or etc inserted.

Comment: When you see the "install windows" options look for a "repair computer" option to get to the command prompt.  If that isn't there <SHIFT> <F8>  OR <SHIFT> <F10>.  Then you can start **chkdsk /R c:** then **chkdsk /R d:**, **chkdsk /R e:**.  You may only have a C: drive so if d: and e: comeback as non-existant or not found don't worry about it.